# Animating wheel rotation with transform constraint to a proxy rigid body

Tags: rigid-body-simulation, constraints

I'm animating a car to collide with some passive object. The car is parented to a proxy rigid body object, which I'm animating for the first part, and then the animation is turned off so the physics takes over.
For the wheel rotation, I use a transform constraint so that the local X location affects the local Y rotation of the wheels (with a negative sign). The wheels appear to rotate correctly as long as I'm animating the proxy object, but after the collision, the wheels continue to rotate forward even though the car (proxy object) is traveling backwards after the collision (bouncing off the object). I stepped through the frames and noticed that after the collision, the location of the proxy object is no longer updated. Has anyone noticed this, and how can I get the location of the proxy object after the collision?

The proxy object is animated from frame 1 through 60 just prior to collision.
The rigid body "Animated" box is checked until frame 55, and unchecked from frame 56 onward.